# Django: extra_content for class based view not displaying any data

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a site that displays all of the items in a "case", and at the top I want to display the total value of all of the items in the "case". To get this number you would get all of the items in the case, multiply their value and quantity and add them all up. However when I pass this to my `extra_content` nothing is displayed.**Any help would be awesome!**

My View:

```py
class CaseHome(ListView):
    model = CaseItem
    template_name = 'mycase/casehome.html'
    total = CaseItem.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum(F('Item_Price')*F('Item_Quantity')))['total']
    extra_content = {'my_total': total}
```

My Model:

```py
class CaseItem(models.Model):
    Item_Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Item_Price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    Item_Quantity = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Item_Title + ' | ' + str(self.Item_Quantity) + ' * $' + str(self.Item_Price)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

My Template:

```py
{% block content %}
    <p>{{my_total}}</p>
    {% for item in object_list %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item" style="border: 2px solid black; margin: 3px; padding: 3px">
                <a href="{% url 'item-editor' item.pk %} "><h3 style="display: inline-block">{{ item.Item_Title }}</h3><h5 style="float: right"><span class="badge bg-info text-dark">Quantity:{{ item.Item_Quantity}}</span> <span class="badge bg-info text-dark" style="margin-left: 15px;"> Price: ${{item.Item_Price}} </span>
            </div>
            </h5></a>
            <hr>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to set `extra_context` not `extra_content`

Comment: @IainShelvington *Face Palm*. Quick Question though, is using `extra_context` a common/proper practice or is it more of an edge case?

Comment: The way you are using it has issues and I would recommend overriding the `get_context_data` method instead. `total` is defined on the class and will not dynamically update when the data changes, you would have to restart the application to update the value currently. I've seen it used more often as an argument passed in the url configuration (as a parameter to `as_view`), as a way to reuse the same view with some customisation but for static values

Comment: @IainShelvington How would i do it with `get_context_data`?

Comment: Added an answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

You should override `get_context_data` instead. Defining `total` on the class means that it will not update when the data changes it's executed only once when the application starts, you should execute the query on every request to get up-to-date data

```
class CaseHome(ListView):
    model = CaseItem
    template_name = 'mycase/casehome.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['my_total'] = CaseItem.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum(F('Item_Price')*F('Item_Quantity')))['total']
        return context
```